# Add cells values based on key word in adjacent cell string - kind of sumif?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I´ve a row that includes full sentences, each word or number is in a different cell.
I want to add a column at the right end, summing up all the values that are at the left of my keyword.

So, let´s say you´ve the following for row A:

```
       10,000║ Revenue ║ related ║ to ║ June ║ sales. ║ -52.45 ║  Operative ║ costs. ║ -300 ║ revenue ║ correction ║ for ║ June ║ period.
```

My result should be: 9,700.

This, taking into account my keyword is "Revenue", or "revenue", or "Rev.", and other variations of the same word I´d be able to list.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: With your sample data in A1:O1, the simple version would be `=SUMIF(B1:O1,"revenue",A1:N1)` or possibly with a wildcard as `=SUMIF(B1:O1,"rev*",A1:N1)`. However, you have not disclosed enough information on the number of, storage and retrieval of the list of keywords you plan to use. There may be better methods depending on that factor.

Answer (score 0):

In cell P1, paste the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("rev",B1)),A1,)
```

Use the mouse to extend the formula to the right to cell Y1.

The formula does a case-insensitive search of the cell to see if it contains "rev".  This will capture "Revenue", "revenue", and "rev".  If there's a match, then it copies the cell to the left.  Otherwise it enters 0.

Now, in cell Z1, simply sum cells P1 through Y1:

```
=SUM(P1:Y1)
```

Now, select P1 through Z1 and extend down for all of the rows you need to evaluate.

For your sample row, this yields the following in P1 - Z1:

```
10000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -300 | 9700
```

Comment: I would use the formula `IF(LEFT(B1,3)="REV",A1,0)` but yours works.